# Spotify (Libspotify) - get a list of a user playlist

Tags: ruby, spotify, libspotify

We have developed a web application using libspotify. The application collects public playlists of users to give them a result. We find that for users previous to July the application works properly but it doesn't work with users created after that date. We are unable get their playlists (time out error).

We are thinking that it may be related to the launch of the new version of spotify API, but we haven´t received information that indicated that the version we use has been deprecated.

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/

Does anybody know if the new API changes anything for new users?  What changes have resulted for new users?

Do the new changes affect the libspotify?

Here is an example of this with a new user:

https://back.spotifyrankings.com/users/spotify:user:11154275134

Here is example with an existing user:

https://back.spotifyrankings.com/users/spotify:user:dogeatcat

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know nothing has changed that makes this not work.
However, I would encourage you to use the Web API instead of Libspotify for fetching this information from a web application.

For fetching user's playlists you could use the [Client Credentials](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) OAuth 2 flow.

Comment: JMPerez' answer is correct. libspotify was *never* meant to be used in backend instances like this and you're going to be forever running into trouble like this. You really, really, REALLY should move over to the new Web API - it's designed for exactly the kind of thing you're doing.

Comment: Ouch!... and there is nothing we could do to resolve our problem for the moment while we migrated to the new API?